# Spring Security is not working - HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: security, post, spring-security, http-status-code-405

I'am having a problem with Spring Security which now bang my head. When i try to submit a login then this error message is displayed: "**HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported**". I have read a ton of articles related to this issue but still not lucky.

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "vn.com.tma.hrm.security" })

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .and()
        .csrf();
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    db.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return db;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

}
}
```

application context:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="vn.com.tma.hrm"></context:component-scan>
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
      <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
      <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
      <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
      <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
  </mvc:interceptors>
  <!-- handle default url "/" -->
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
  <!-- mapping default url "/" to "home" -->
  <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home1"/>
  
  <!-- static resources mapping -->
  <mvc:resources mapping="/libs/**" location="/libs/"></mvc:resources>
  <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"></mvc:resources>
  <mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/"></mvc:resources>

  <!-- JPA configurations -->
  <jpa:repositories base-package="vn.com.tma.hrm.repository" 
                    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"
                    transaction-manager-ref="txManager"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:application.properties" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="hrmDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hrmDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="${entitymanager.packages.to.scan}" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
  </bean>
  <tx:annotation-driven />

  <!-- Spring data REST configurations -->
  <bean id="baseUri" class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.BaseUri">
    <constructor-arg value="/api" />
  </bean>
  <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"/> -->
</beans>
```

Dispatcher Servlet

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Login Form

```html
<c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
<form name="myForm" action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
 <%-- <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/> --%>
 <fieldset>
  <label class="block clearfix">
   <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
        name="email" id="email" ng-model="email" ng-trim="true" required="true" ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/"
      ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10"/>
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
   </span>
  </label>

  <label class="block clearfix">
   <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"
        ng-model="password" required="true" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10" ng-trim="true" />
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
   </span>
  </label>

  <div class="space"></div>

  <div class="clearfix">
   <c:if test="${loginView == null}">
    <label class="inline">
     <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
     <span class="lbl"> Remember Me</span>
    </label>
   </c:if>
   <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
    <span class="bigger-110">Login</span>
   </button>
  </div>

  <div class="space-4"></div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please help me on this!

**Updated**

Adding web.xml file:

```html
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Spring MVC DispatcherServlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: how did you load those xml bean definition and java configuration? using web.xml or WebInitializer...

Comment: I load those xml beans by using web.xml file. I have just posted web.xml source.